# tslint rxjs-tslint-rules Cannot find '/users/whisher/projects/my/src/rxjs-imports.ts' in the compiled program. Has it been imported?

Tags: angular, rxjs, tslint

I've add this linter rxjs-tslint-rules
to my tslint.json like

```
"extends": [
    "rxjs-tslint-rules"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "rxjs-add": {
      "options": [{
        "allowElsewhere": false,
        "allowUnused": false,
        "file": "./src/rxjs-imports.ts"
    }],
    "severity": "error"
  },
```

and of course I've add in the src folder
the rxjs-imports.ts file

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

than in my main.ts

```
import './rxjs-imports';
```

but I get

**Cannot find '/users/whisher/projects/my/src/rxjs-imports.ts' in the compiled program. Has it been imported?**

How can I fix it ?

or is it a bug ?

### UPDATE

I've seen just now with the brand new 5.5 version
there are lettable operators so the rxjs-imports file
now is quite useless.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md

Comment: There are some related ([now closed](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed)) issues in GitHub. It is likely a configuration issue. Make sure you've read the Angular gotchas in the README. And there is now a working Angular CLI example in the repo.

Comment: I dont find any example :( can you link me please ?

Comment: It's [here](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules/tree/master/examples/ng-cli-example) and the [README](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules/blob/master/README.md#angularcli) includes links to the pre and post lint config commits, so that the config changes are clear.

Comment: I've just seen jsut now in the 5.5 version there are lettable operators so rxjs-imports file is quite useless but thanks for the help.

Comment: @Whisher Using an rxjs-imports file is still recommended for reducing bundle size in Angular projects. From the official rxjs documentation:
"Pipeable operators can now be imported from `rxjs/operators`, but doing so without changing your build process will often result in a larger application bundle. This is because by default `rxjs/operators` will resolve to the CommonJS output of rxjs."
(source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking)
(official bug report: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9069)

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
"files": [
  "../src/rxjs-imports.ts"
]
```

to `tsconfig.e2e.json` fixed it for me.

Full config is as follows:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc/e2e",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasminewd2",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "../src/rxjs-imports.ts"
  ]
}
```

and `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```